# iOS Autolayout with Tab Bar

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a pretty simple view hierarchy here:
`Navigation Controller (opaque bar) -> Tab Controller (opaque bar) -> View -> Subview`
Subview is inset by 10 points from each side of the View with constraints: Leading and Trailing space to container and Top and Bottom Layout guides.

[image: Layout]

It looks ok in storyboard:

[image: Storyboard layout]

But if I run the app, the top of the subview is inset for extra 10 points or so. What's the reason of this and how can I achieve a proper spacing as configured?

[image: Actual layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the constraints, I can see the problem.

Your vertical constraint is not 10 points from Subview to View, the constraint is 10 points from Subview to [Top Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html).

Apple picks [Top Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html) by default, but you can manually set the constraint to be from subview to view.

Comment: Using the Interface Builder I can't pick the view top spacing, if I ctrl-drag from subview to view, there's only top and bottom layout guides available. I'll try to do it programmatically, although I can't yet understand, why the layout guide appears to be below the actual window top edge

Comment: Ok, I've tried to pin subview's top and bottom to superview's from the code and it seems to work fine, thanks. Just curious why I can't select these constraints from IB